# joomla "hooks" assistance

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Im new to joomla so excuse the possible confused-ness in my part

im developing a site in joomla and in the beginning, i registered the sections i wanted on the site via the xml. i was specific because i knew what i wanted (or so i thought)

so for example, sprinkled throughout the page, i have some of these:

```
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="sidebar" style="xhtml" /></div>
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="xhtml" /></div>
```

now, i need more sections and so to try, i tried to copy/paste an extra

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="TESTSection" style="xhtml" /></div>
```

on the page to see if joomla would pick it up in the module manager when trying to assign
a new section to the page but it didnt. when i go to assign a new module to this new line (TESTSection) it doesnt appear...the only ones that appear are the ones i initially registered with the xml.

my question is, do i have to put in a new line in the xml that coincides with the new section i want to add or??? do i have to reinstall my template with the sections i want again or....how do i go about assigning a new "hook" to the page so
that joomla can bite?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `</div>` at the end. Well, not to display the module.

The answer to your questions about the new line in the xml of the template is YES.

You don't need to reinstall the template, just edit your xml and your php file.

Comment: ohh sorry, was a quick copy/paste lol. but ok so your saying edit the XML file to have the new "hooks" and then theyll appear on the page